# Restore "manage this printer" permissions in windows

Tags: windows, permissions, printer

I screwed up and got myself locked out from managing some of my printers on windows server 2012.

I removed the "manage this printer" permission from all accounts, but accidentally included my administrator account. So now I cannot add or remove permissions with any account at all. I cannot remove the printer either.

So the question is what could I do to restore such permission - my guess is I would have to either use an elevated cmd to add permissions through some command or manually overwrite the registry with valid permissions.

I thought maybe overwriting the binary blob at the `Security` key in:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Print\Printers\MyPrinterName]
```

would do the trick, but not sure if that's enough. I don't like messing about the registry because you can never be absolutely sure you've adjusted everything you need so a command would be much better.

Since it is a Windows server version there's no system restore available, and the latest system state backup is no good because it had the issue already.

I have been able to workaround the problem by creating a new printer using the same port, but I would really like to remove the old faulty ones, for that I need the manage permissions.

I guess that removing the printer from the registry should also do the trick, but this seemed like a perfect opportunity to learn.

Comment: Unless you explicitly set deny rights, you should be able to add the rights back by using an administrator account the same way you removed them. Just because you don't have the rights to manage the printer doesn't mean you also don't have the rights to change its permissions. If that really doesn't work, see if you can somehow push the rights from a higher level.

Comment: when your user or user group is not in the list under the security tab, the option to add or delete is disabled, advanced options however is enabled, which is how I recovered ownership of the printer and set the permissions back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tested this, but this is how rights work in windows, so it should work.

Right-click your printer and go to printer properties.

Now head to the security tab.

Click a group such that the <kbd>Advanced</kbd> button becomes active. You can already try to set the permissions here, but lets assume you cannot, go to advanced.

At the top, it will say Owner: SYSTEM. Change this to your own user with administrative rights.

Once you have done this, regardless of what permissions you have, you can now set the proper permissions, either from the advanced tab or one screen earlier. You may have to close and reopen that settings screen though.

Don't forget to set the owner back to SYSTEM once you're done.

Comment: Super simple and helpful, it was that easy after all

Answer (score 0):

The best way to get around the issue, since you have removed the Administrator account from the Printer Permissions, is to remove the Printers from the effected PCs/Laptops via the Registry. (https://www.online-tech-tips.com/computer-tips/cannot-remove-or-delete-network-printer/)

You then would need to remove the Printer from the Print Server if you are using a Print Server and then simply re-publish the same Printer under the same name and assign it via a GPO to the Users.

Hope this helps.

Kind Regards,
Mo

Comment: useful information to delete printers, thank you, however the answer explaining hor to retrieve ownership and therefore modify permissions works better for my scenario.